# linear transformations and images of a line

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a bit confused here. Any help is appreciated.

So we have a line $L =  3x - 2y -5 = 0 $ and a matrix A

$$A =\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
1 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Find a line whose image under $A$ is $L$. I'm going to call that line $P$

So $A(P) = L$. To find P, we must get $A^{-1} L$?

I'm confused on how to multiply a matrix by a line.

Comment: Multiply each point of $L$ by the matrix.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain, I don't fully understand what you mean

Comment: Take a point (**column** vector) $v=(x,y)$ s.t. $3x−2y−5$ and do $A^{-1}v$.

Answer (score 0):

You are given the affine subspace $L=\{(x,y)^T\in\mathbb R^2\mid 3x-2y-5=0\}$. Now $A(x',y')^T=(x'+3y',x'+4y')^T\in L\iff 3(x'+3y')-2(x'+4y')-5=0$. Thus, $P=\{(x',y')^T\mid x'+y'-5=0\}$ is a one-dimensional subspace satisfying $A(P)\subset L$.

As $\det A\neq 0$ and $A$ is therefore invertible, $A(P)$ is a one-dimensional affine subspace of $L$, hence $A(P)=L$.

Of course you can check surjectivity by hand instead of using this dimension argument if you are more comfortable with that.

Comment: you might have a minor typo though of course the procedure is correct. The upper left entry of $A$ is $2$, not $1$.